# What's the densest alkali metal?

Tags: metal, reference-request, alkali-metals

This was asked in a school exam of mine, GCSE curriculum, exactly as it was worded on the title. I found this question a bit vague, and answered it **francium**, however of course francium is just an estimation. I couldn't be sure what the answer to the question would be, so can anyone give me some insight?

Comment: The question is _more than_ a bit vague. Privately I consider Cs the right answer, but they most likely wanted you to say Fr, even though Fr is not really a thing.

Comment: According to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkalimetalle#Trends Fr is even sligthly less dense than Cs. Also sodium is definitely denser than potassium. The upward trend just isn't perfectly clean. All in all, this is quite a stupid question to ask in an exam. Do they want you to learn these numbers by heart?

Comment: Otoh, all period 7 elements are considerably denser than their counterparts in period 6, and those than theirs in 5. Only periods 2-4 are not continguous. I think I knew this at the end of high school. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell what is the answer you *were supposed* to provide, but yes, generally speaking, you are correct.
According to *CRC handbook of chemistry and physics* [1, p. 4-14] (emphasis mine):

> Francium, **the heaviest known member of the alkali metal series**, occurs as a result of an alpha disintegration of actinium. […]
>
> Because all known isotopes of francium are highly unstable, knowledge of the chemical properties of this element comes from radiochemical techniques. **No weighable quantity
> of the element has been prepared or isolated**.

As the result, the majority of physical properties of [francium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium), including density, were obtained by extrapolation and not by direct measurements.
According to Bonchev and Kamenska [[2](https://doi.org/10.1021/j150609a021)], $ρ_\mathrm{calcd.}(\ce{Fr}) \approx \pu{2.9 g cm-3}$, which is in a good agreement with the trend for the measured densities across the group.
For comparison, the following data (NTP conditions) is collected from the table *PHYSICAL CONSTANTS OF INORGANIC COMPOUNDS* [1, p. 4-43]:

$$
\begin{array}{cl}
\hline
\text{Element} & ρ/\pu{g cm-3} \\
\hline
\ce{Li} & 0.534 \\
\ce{Na} & 0.97 \\
\ce{K} & 0.89 \\
\ce{Rb} & 1.53 \\
\ce{Cs} & 1.873 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

#### References

1. Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data.; *CRC Press*, **2017**; Vol. 97. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.
2. Bonchev, D.; Kamenska, V. Predicting the Properties of the 113-120 Transactinide Elements. *J. Phys. Chem.* **1981**, 85 (9), 1177–1186. https://doi.org/10.1021/j150609a021.

Comment: A linear extrapolation though Li-Cs runs almost exactly though the value of 2.9 at 223. Bit weird, that.